# Fragment is not detected inside Linear layout

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I tried to create a fragment inside a Linear Layout, but it shows some error which I have attached as an image:

[image]

It says Linear layout has invalid child element fragment. I am very new to Xamarin Android and I have done this by referring a tutorial shown in this link: [creating_a_fragment](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/)

Can someone help me find a solution for this?

Comment: Seems like a xml schema problem. Could you please try compile the project anyway, and see what errors you got?

Comment: Go to the schema website http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android and check requirements.